# Tracking a Chrome extension's version with Google Analytics custom variables

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

So I have a Chrome extension which uses Google Analytics for tracking various things. One of those things is the extension version, set using a custom variable every time the background page is started. Now my question is: Which scope should I use, visitor or session level? I can't figure it out based on Google's documentation, and no one else seems to have had this issue. I'm not even sure there's any difference, or maybe it's just something like "it's bad practice to overwrite visitor level variables".

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions are have some very specific characteristics and the answer to this question is not applicable to anything that is not a Chrome extension.

From your question I believe you do some basic tracking on your background page, but I assume you also do so on a popup or you fire an event if the user do some action with your extension.

In that case I'll strongly suggest that you use a **Visitor Level** Custom var.

The problem is that the background page is loaded only once, when the browser opens up, and it's like a tab that stays open and silent, possibly hosting some callback functions for events that may or may not happen.

Because of that once the visitor first loads your extension you'll see a pageview from you background page setting this custom var.

After that there may be a silent period where your extension doesn't track anything, this period can take hours, until hopefully the user interacts with your extensions and tracks additional data to analytics. When it finally happens chances are that over half an hour has passed since the backgroun page loaded. If that is true the visit (or session) that was started by the background page is already over. A visit with no activity for 30 min is closed by analytics. In that case that interaction will spawn a new visit.

If you set the Custom Var as a visit leve variable chances are that when you see interactions on the extension, these interactions won't have the custom var.

This approach has the bad side effect that if the version of your extension changes and the user doesn't reload the browser the version is not going to be updated, and it will be erroneously registered as te old version.

That's very unlikely. And the only way to fix it is to check the version of your app everytime the user does an interaction and set that custom var again. I believe that this is excessive and I don't do it in my extension. Still if you opt for it, it really doesn't matter if it's a visit level or visitor level custom var.

Comment: You're correct, except I also set "_setSessionCookieTimeout" to 0 when the background page launches, so theoretically a session should last until the browser closes...
I'm slightly confused about the last bit though. The only time the version should change is when the extension is updated, which also causes the background page to reload, which sets the custom variable. So shouldn't it be a non-issue?

Comment: I didn't know the background page would reload after an update. But thinking again, it makes sense. I work primarily with Google Analytics for almost 3 years now, it's very rare to learn something new. But you just thought me about the _setSessionCookieTimeout, 0. I never heard of that before. Thanks for mentioning it.